# Jetpack compose bottom app bar dark color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm trying to set the navigation bar to the same color as the bottom app bar, but I don't understand where the color for the app bar comes from with the dark theme. It looks like it should be `MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface` but I use `systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface)` the color is not the same as the app bar. Here you see an example when both are set to `MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface`.

[image]

It works fine for the light theme, but not for the dark theme.

So where does the dark theme app bar color come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens because of [**elevationOverlay**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ElevationOverlay) applied in the dark mode.
You can provide `null` as `LocalElevationOverlay` to have no `ElevationOverlay` applied.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalElevationOverlay provides null) {
        BottomAppBar { /* .... */. }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never had figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

Adding explanation to Gabriele answer

For example in BottomNavigation we have this code

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = BottomNavigationDefaults.Elevation,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(BottomNavigationHeight)
                .selectableGroup(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

If we go to the surface elevation attribute before creating the Row component to lay the navigation icons we can see this

```
@Composable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(color),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val absoluteElevation = LocalAbsoluteElevation.current + elevation
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides contentColor,
        LocalAbsoluteElevation provides absoluteElevation
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .surface(
                    shape = shape,
                    backgroundColor = surfaceColorAtElevation(
                        color = color,
                        elevationOverlay = LocalElevationOverlay.current,
                        absoluteElevation = absoluteElevation
                    ),
                    border = border,
                    elevation = elevation
                )
```

Here we can see that `elevationOverlay = LocalElevationOverlay.current` is used to determine the overlay of the bottom nav, and this is because we need to know about dark or light theme because elevations in dark themes does not appear to be so much visible

Read https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ElevationOverlay